# Can the salt in the encryption key can be different for encryption and decryption?

Tags: java, encryption, salt

I have a java application that encrypts and decrypts strings. It generates one key for encryption and one for decryption.

Key Generation:

```
 SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
 char[] passwordChars = password.toCharArray();
 KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passwordChars, salt.getBytes(), iterations, 256);
 SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(spec);
 byte[] passwordHash = key.getEncoded();
 SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");
```

My goal is to have the password stay the same for both the encryption and decryption key. But have a different salt for each of them. Is this possible or do I need to have the same salt for both keys?

Whenever I try to change the salt for the decryption key, I get this error:

```
javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:623)
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1118)
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1055)
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:855)
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2207)
```

Comment: please specify the salt and iterations.

Comment: The salt is used to generate a key from the passphrase (using PBKDF2). Changing the salt or iteration count will change the generated key, so no, you can't do that, AES uses symmetric keys, so encryption and decryption keys must be the same.

Comment: Iterations = 6000 // salt for key1 = "salt"  (encryption key) //  salt for key2 = "test" (decryption key). This is just a test application at the moment, so I'm not generating random salts just yet.

Comment: Thanks Marc. My encryption and decryption keys are actually different. The application works as long as the keys generated use the same password, salt and IV. I just wanted to make sure there was no way of randomising the salt on each key generation.

Comment: They can differ between two messages, but if you're using AES-GCM, the raw keys need to be the same. If you're using the same password/salt/iteration, the keys will be identical. You should only change the parameters when you want different keys (eg: from one message to another), but not between encryption and decryption. You saw first hand what happens when you change the salt.

Comment: Right, that is the answer I was looking for. Thanks for the help Marc.

Answer (score 0):

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm - the salt should be different for each piece of encrypted information. I believe its often derivable from the user's other details... so dob + last name (for example) are used as the salt for encrypting passwords so that each password is encrypted to a different value, even when two users share the same password.

Edit: the salt should be the same for the encryption and decryption key, but unique for the individual passwords being encrypted/decrypted. Please read the information at the URL for a better understanding

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. This isn't about password hashing, it's about generating a symmetric key and whether the parameters need to be the same to encrypt and decrypt one message.

Comment: amended my comment to make it more obvious what the solution is. I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is still wrong. Your link is about salting and hashing passwords, not password-based key derivation functions.

Comment: @Marc: The underlying principle is the same, but the use and implementation are different. In both cases salts are used to prevent pre-computation attacks against low-entropy keys like passwords and pass phrases.